# IE6 - Background img missing, extra pixels in header, and most content off center

Tags: internet-explorer-6, background-image, center

Having major issues getting my wordpress website to display correctly in IE6.

Link to screenshot below.  My background image is missing, the nav is knocked down a few extra pixels, and most of my content is off center.

www.genevarealtytrust.com/content/wp-content/themes/wp-terra-basic/images/ie6_wpterra.jpg

FF screenshot (linked below) is what it should look like.  Have tried in Safari, a couple versions of Firefox, and IE7, and all look just the way that they are supposed to.  IE6 is the only one giving me trouble.

www.genevarealtytrust.com/content/wp-content/themes/wp-terra-basic/images/ff_wpterra.jpg

Any ideas??

Link: www.genevarealtytrust.com/content

I've validated my code, and have tried a few things, but no success.

Help!  Appreciate it!

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll realize validating code doesn't mean a thing when it comes to IE6.

Comment: haha yes.... i'm definitely there....

so what do you do?  scrap your site and start over and hope it works out next time around?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using conditional styles. In document's **head** section paste:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" href=www.example.com/ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Now You can start editing ie.css without worrying about spoiling design for other browser.

Extra space around nav: IE sometimes has default margins/paddings different from other browsers. Try defining

```
#something {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}
```

explicitly in Your new css.

No background: Maybe it's the alignment. Try adding somethig like "top left" to Your background-image definition. Example:

```
background-image: url('../img/site-bg.jpg') no-repeat scroll top right;
```

Content centering: In CSS there are two ways to center content. First: setting the parent element **text-align** property to **center;**. Second: Defining **width** and setting **margin** to **top-bottom-margin-value auto;**. Example:

```
#something {
 width: 100px;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
```

I hope this will help solve any of Your problems :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question (and since I don't have enough rep to comment :) ), but try running through [this list](http://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/) of common IE CSS bugs. It's helped me work out some kinks in my CSS, but IE 6 is a warzone. Otherwise, I'd really suggest getting the fantastic book [Bulletproof Web Design](http://simplebits.com/publications/bulletproof/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips guys!  Daveslab, I'll definitely keep that list handy, and thanks for the book recommendation.

**Centering Issue/Missing Background Image:**

I made the alternate css doc and that gave me more room to experiment - I was able to resolve the missing background image and centering issue by simplifying the CSS a bit for the problematic section by trial and error.  (removed float, position...)

**Extra pixels:**

What finally ended up fixing the 3 pixels on the bottom of my header was... just stupid.

Evidently IE6 was applying an extra 3 pixels to the bottom of the header image because my html code for that div was split into 3 lines...

```
<div id="header">
<img src="url" />
</div>
```

I just had to combine them all into one line, and the extra padding on the bottom disappeared.  Dumb... (and ugly)

```
<div id="header"><img src="url" /></div>
```

I still have an extra pixel on the right side that I'm trying to resolve - still investigating.